# Is it possible to test whether small caps are available with the current font?

Tags: fonts, conditionals, small-caps

Is it possible to test, in the document body, whether small caps are available with the current font (both for `pdf(la)tex` and `xe(la)tex`)? What I'd like to do is something like:

```
\usepackage{xifthen}
...
\ifthenelse{<small caps are available with the current font>}{%
  \textsc{my text}%
}{%
  \uppercase{my text}%
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Edit

OK as David pointed out in the comment, simply looking at `\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc` is not enough as this command is defined during a substitution. So one probably has to record if a substitution takes place:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\def\define@newfont{%
  \begingroup
    \let\typeout\@font@info
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
       \split@name\expandafter\string\font@name\@nil
      \try@load@fontshape % try always
    \expandafter\ifx
       \csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname \relax
       \expandafter\gdef\csname \curr@fontshape/sub\endcsname{}% new      
      \wrong@fontshape\else
      \extract@font\fi
  \endgroup}

\newcommand\testsc{%
 \ifcsname \f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc/sub\endcsname
  no
 \else 
  \ifcsname \f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc\endcsname  yes \else no \fi
 \fi   
 \textsc{Aa}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\testsc

\bfseries \testsc 

\scshape \testsc

\end{document}
```

## Edit 2

Instead of patching `\define@newfont` one could also patch `\wrong@fontshape`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\wrong@fontshape{\expandafter\gdef\csname \curr@fontshape/sub\endcsname{}}
....
```

[image]

Comment: It's not always easy to interpret the result of that test, eg `\bfseries \scshape \testsc` typesets bold **Aa** but says yes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are right, I hadn't realized that the substituation defines the macro. But your test has the same problem: If one adds `\bfseries\scshape` before the test one gets yes twice.

Comment: oops:-) I was originally going to do something like this answer then decided it's not really the right test, but as you say mine isn't much better, I think I may delete and come back to it later, the real test is to look in the nfss tables for a substitution rule I suppose but I was trying to avoid that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But I love such digging ...

Comment: don't we all:-)

Comment: Turns out `biblatex` had been using the initial suggestion for years, but that goes wrong: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1093. Is there a way to get the right result without having to patch kernel commands?

Comment: @moewe I need to investigate.  There have been wuote a number of changes to nfss in the last time, and latex-dev just added a new hook.

Comment: @moewe I don't see anything new that could be used. I would suggest that you open an issue at the latex tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the investigation. Feature request at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/471.