# Throw error if font is not defined

Tags: fonts, errors, package-writing

I need to throw an error, should a certain font not be installed.

I have a font in a subfolder: `/font/NinjaFont.ttf`. This must be installed via certain commands (not important for this - but here: http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php)

**EDIT:**

If it's not installed I get <s>about 200 error messages and</s> 2 warnings:
`...MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-text\pst-text.sty:31: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'T1/Fonts/NinjaFont/m' undefined(Font) using 'T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 31.
...pst-text.sty:31: LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

I need to detect, whether `T1/Fonts/NinjaFont/m` is defined.

The following code can help me some of the way:

```
\PackageError{NinjaPackage}{The ninja font is not defined}{See ninja instructions.}
\stop
```

Not I just need to detect the font, so I can throw the error. Anyone have a solution or pointers to where I can find the answer?

<s>**More EDIT:**</s>

Example files:

*T1-WGL4.enc*:
http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/T1-WGL4.enc

*t1ninja.df*:

```
\ProvidesFile{t1ninja.fd}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{ninja}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{ninja}{m}{n}{ <-> ninja}{}
\pdfmapline{+ninja\space <ninja.ttf\space <T1-WGL4.enc}
```

I think it would be around here, that the compiler realizes, that the font does not exist in the folder with other fonts.

Can I do a `\xifelsethen{ {warningThrown} {Error} {noError} }`?

**EDIT 4:**

Based on previous answers this seems to work out nice. I have to install the package globally, then I'm for sure it will work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\define@newfont{%
  \begingroup
    \let\typeout\@font@info
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
       \split@name\expandafter\string\font@name\@nil
      \try@load@fontshape % try always
    \expandafter\ifx
       \csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname \relax
       \expandafter\gdef\csname \curr@fontshape/sub\endcsname{}% new      
      \wrong@fontshape\else
      \extract@font\fi
  \endgroup}

\newcommand\ninjaFont[1]{%
 { \fontfamily{ninja}\selectfont #1
 \ifcsname \f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/n/sub\endcsname
  \PackageError{NinjaSetup}{Not installed}{Do this}
  \stop
 \else 
 \fi
 }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ninjaFont{It works?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `T1/Fonts/NinjaFont/m` looks odd, I doubt that you did setup the font commands correctly. Beside this: You get only a warning not an error if this font is undefined. Better make a complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You are correct. I messed up!

Comment: Your font setup is wrong, you seem to use a foldername as familyname. You could probably adapt the code here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218539/is-it-possible-to-test-whether-small-caps-are-available-with-the-current-font/218552#218552 but without an example I won't test.

Comment: Added minimum example

Comment: If your fd-filed is named t1ninja and font family "ninja" you must call the font as `\usefont{T1}{ninja}{m}{n} `. And if the ttf-file is named `NinjaFont.ttf` you must adapt the `\pdfmapline` command. Beside this it is unclear if you want to check if the fd-file or the ttf-file exists.

Comment: I want to check, if I can use the font. According to the site I must run the command `ttf2tfm custom.ttf -p T1-WGL4.enc` to install it (haven't tried yet, because I need to see what happens when you haven't). That command will store the font in a usable format for tex to use.

Comment: It's a lot easier to use XeTeX

Comment: You need to check the existence of the tfm and and ttf. That's not difficult for the current folder but not so easy if they are somewhere in the texsystem.

Comment: Do you want it to say, as I think it will, that the font is not installed if somebody uses the command after switching to bold weight or italic shape or whatever? Which 'previous answer'?

Comment: @cft: I want it to say, that it cannot find that particular font (including shape and all). But I think the last bit of code does the trick.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to add an answer, if you find an answer it is OK to post an answer. Note that `{ \fontfamily` will insert a space before the text every time you select the font, and `#1 ` will insert a space after the text. But your question (and answer) are very unclear. If you specify a font and it is not on your system then you get an error from latex without adding any new definitions. In what way do you need to change the behaviour?